# TesseractNotFoundError: <full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable> is not installed or it's not in your PATH

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract

> when I'm open the image and digitization then it gives error
>   I am run this code on jupyter notebook windows 10. I have installed pytesseract and tesseract also using pip command

### This is my code

```
    try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
# pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
# Example tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

# Simple image to string
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('Train/TR_1.jpg')))
```

### It gives error when I run given code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    237     try:
--> 238         proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
    239     except OSError as e:

~\anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    799                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 800                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    801         except:

~\anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1206                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1207                                          startupinfo)
   1208             finally:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TesseractNotFoundError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-518675d4cb18> in <module>
     10 
     11 # Simple image to string
---> 12 print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('Train/TR_1.jpg')))
     13 
     14 # # French text image to string

~\anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in image_to_string(image, lang, config, nice, output_type, timeout)
    358         Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},
    359         Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
--> 360     }[output_type]()
    361 
    362 

~\anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in <lambda>()
    357         Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),
    358         Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},
--> 359         Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
    360     }[output_type]()
    361 

~\anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_and_get_output(image, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout, return_bytes)
    268         }
    269 
--> 270         run_tesseract(**kwargs)
    271         filename = kwargs['output_filename_base'] + extsep + extension
    272         with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:

~\anaconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    240         if e.errno != ENOENT:
    241             raise e
--> 242         raise TesseractNotFoundError()
    243 
    244     with timeout_manager(proc, timeout) as error_string:

TesseractNotFoundError: <full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable> is not installed or it's not in your PATH
```

> > I am run this code on jupyter notebook windows 10. I have installed pytesseract and tesseract also using pip command

Answer (score 0):

You must install tesseract itself first. In Centos you call do this by running

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo 
https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexander_Pozdnyakov/CentOS_7/
rpm --import https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:Alexander_Pozdnyakov/public_key
yum install -y tesseract  tesseract-langpack-deu
```

There should be an equivalent also in windows OS which can be found here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki

pytesseract is just a wrapper of the tesseract package.

Comment: is there any way to install tesseract-ocr using pip command in anaconda windows 10 os ?

Comment: there is no way, you can download windows binary and install it such as .exe or .msi. Follow the link in my answer because Windows binary is included in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line, with path (for example)

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
```

before

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('Train/TR_1.jpg')))
```

Having previously downloaded and installed the executable file for windows https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki

Comment: Tesseract-OCR file is not available in the program file